# I am using Pywinauto and Outlook and when I try to do a click on a MenuItem "Attach File", I get an "ElementNotFoundError". Any advice on this?

Tags: python, outlook, pywinauto

So far, I was able to open the Outlook app, click on "New Email", provide the recipient, and provide a message. Now I am trying to attach a file which is giving me some issues. `self.newEmail` is what I assigned to the window. I did `self.newEmail['Attach File...'].click()` and I get the following error `Exception has occurred: ElementNotFoundError`. I tried other variations of that as explained in the Getting Started Guide but I continue to receive the same error. When I do `dump_tree()` I get the following control identifier for that MenuItem:

```
MenuItem - 'Attach File...'    (L2821, T67, R2863, B140)
['MenuItem11', 'Attach File...', 'Attach File...MenuItem']
child_window(title="Attach File...", control_type="MenuItem")
```

I would like to "Browse This PC":

[image]

Here is my code (I am getting an error in my last line):

```
self.outlook = self.app.window(title_re =self.appName)
self.outlook.child_window(title_re="New Email", control_type="Button").click()
self.outlook.wait('visible', timeout = 20)
        
self.newEmail = self.app.window(title_re="Untitled")
self.newEmail['Edit5'].type_keys("JohnDoe@gmail.com", with_spaces=True)
self.newEmail['Edit7'].type_keys("Sample Subject", with_spaces=True)
send_keys("{ENTER}")
send_keys("I am writing a message", with_spaces=True)

self.newEmail = self.app.window(title_re="Untitled")
self.newEmail.descendants(title="Attach File...", control_type="MenuItem")[0].click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the generated python script from Pywinauto recorder (I am developing this Open source tool available on github):

```
with Window(u"Untitled - Message (HTML) ||Window"):
    wrapper = find(u"MsoDockTop||Pane->||ToolBar->Ribbon||Pane->||Pane->||Pane->Ribbon||Pane->Lower Ribbon||Pane->Message||Custom->Include||Group->Attach File...||MenuItem")
```

As you can see "Attach File..." with MenuItem control_type is not a direct child of the new email window. So you should try with descendants:

```
new_email_window.descendants(title="Attach File...", control_type="MenuItem")
```

Comment: That's a pretty nice script you got there. I tried using descendants and I am still receiving the same error. `Exception has occurred: ElementNotFoundErrorException`

Comment: So it means that the problem comes from how you get your new_email_window wrapper. Could you write your code?

Comment: I've added it above in the posted question